# Obtaining a Synchronized List of BlockingQueues in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, concurrency, blockingqueue, synchronizedcollection

I'd like to work with the following data structure:

```
List<BlockingQueue<AtomicInteger>> listOfQueues = 
    Collections.synchronizedList(
        new ArrayList<ArrayBlockingQueue<AtomicInteger>>(15)
    );
```

So I'd like to construct a list of initially empty `BlockingQueue`s in such a way that every single `BlockingQueue` shall encapsulate `AtomicInteger`s. I know that `BlockingQueue` is an inteface that shall be implemented by for example `ArrayBlockingQueue`.

It's also important to obtain a synchonizedList of `15` elements.

I printed out the size of the synchonizedList and it yielded `0`.

How to fix the aforementioned issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By specifying the capacity argument of the `ArrayList`'s constructor, you're changing the size of it's underlying array. It has no impact on the contents of the list. You need to add the queues manually.

Also note that some implementations of the `BlockingQueue` like [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#constructor-summary) require specifying the initial capacity of the queue in the constructor.

Here's how it can be done with Stream API by using Collector [`collectingAndThen()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.Function)) with Collector `toList()` as a downstream and a *function* that produces asynchronized List.

```
final int queueCapacity = // the required capacity of the queues
final int limit = // required number of queues
    
var listOfQueues = 
    Stream.generate(() -> new ArrayBlockingQueue<AtomicInteger>(capacity))
        .limit(limit)
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.toList(),
            Collections::synchronizedList
        ));
```

Or you can do it using a plane `for`-loop like that:

```
final int capacity = // the required capacity of the queues
final int limit = // required number of queues
    
List<ArrayBlockingQueue<AtomicInteger>> listOfQueues = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    listOfQueues.add(new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(capacity));
}
        
var synchronizedListOfQueues = Collections.synchronizedList(listOfQueues);
```